# Writing to XML file in Android

Tags: android, xml

I'm trying to write to an XML file, within my XML file I have:

```
<user>
   <name></name>
</user>
```

And the method I can to write to the XML file:

```
public void WriteToXML() throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException {
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(inputStream);
    Element element = doc.getDocumentElement();
    element.normalize();
    NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("user");
    Node node = nList.item(0);

    if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

        Element element2 = (Element) node;
        if(element2.getTagName() == "name")
        {
            element2.setNodeValue("SFDSFSDF");
        }

    }
}
```

However, the method gets called but for some reason it doesnt actually write to the XML file because when I read it their isn't actually anything within the XML?

Comment: You probably shouldn't use `== "name"`

Comment: @cricket_007 How would I declare which tag to insert in? Since I may have multiple tags within <user>

Comment: That's just not how to [compare strings in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: @cricket_007 Okay, I replaced it.. do you have any idea why it still doesn't work?

Comment: I'm guessing that `element2.setNodeValue` changes the value in memory. No part of your code modifies or writes to the file

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace :

```
element2.getTagName() == "name"
```

by :

```
(element2.getTagName()).equals("name")
```

Also, try to replace :

```
element2.setNodeValue("SFDSFSDF");
```

by :

```
element2.setTextContent("SFDSFSDF");  //adds content
```

Comment: This wont actually write to the xml file right? it would just change in memory?

Comment: The getNodeValue() / setNodeValue() methods work differently depending on what type of Node you have.

Comment: So how do i actually write to the file

Comment: setNodeValue() works on Text Nodes. If the node is an Element then setting nodeValue does nothing.

Comment: Like i said in the answer, to write in the node, you have to replace element2.setNodeValue("YOUR TEXT"); by element2.setTextContent("YOUR TEXT");

Comment: I understand, I've done this.. but it doesn't actually write the xml file when I load the XML file